# Variables in a setTimeout function (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, timeout

I'm trying to use a jQuery statement inside a setTimeout function, but
I don't get it to work. I tried a lot of variants, like this one (I'm
using 'this' because the setTimeout is inside an each function, and
the selector is cached/stored in an object, thus the $selector):

```
setTimeout("" + this.$selector + ".val('" + this.savVal + "')", 1);
```

How do I have to write this?

Thanks!

Comment: Strings in `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` are obsolete. Functions should be used instead.

Answer (score 19):

When you need to preserve the current `this` item when calling setTimeout use this structure:-

```
setTimeout((function(self) {
  return function() { $selector.val(self.savVal) };
})(this), 1);
```

This creates a closure from the outer functions execution context.  The outer function returns an inner function that will have access the `self` parameter.  Its the inner function that gets called when the timeout occurs yet the value of `self` will hold on to the original `this` value.

Comment: Elegant if a bit cryptic to people not familiar with closures. Feel silly this wasn't the first thing that came to mind when I realized IE wasn't passing parameters. I plead ".NET Developer" as my excuse. That's a thing, right?

Answer (score 7):

**AnthonyWJones** provided a great answer, but there's another similar one, which is slightly easier to write and read. You simply store the value of "this" in a local variable., ie.

```
var storedThis = this;
setTimeout(function() { $selector.val(storedThis.savVal); }, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do something like this, if the variables you are trying to use are defined in each step of the loop.

```
var myObj = {
  $selector: myConfigObj.$myCachedSelector
}

$.each([ myObj, mySecondObj, myThirdObj ], function(n, $selector) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $selector.val(saveVal);
    }, 1);
});
```

Comment: Marco, "myConfigObj.$myCachedSelector" seems to be the problem. It returns "undefined". I replaced it with a simple string which gets returned correctly...

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answers.

I'm using a function inside the setTimeout now. But I found out that the real problem lies elswhere: in the each-function I'm trying to access object properties which are pointing to properties within a config object, but the result (for example for this.$selector) is "undefined".

```
var myObj = {
  $selector: myConfigObj.$myCachedSelector
}

$.each([ myObj, mySecondObj, myThirdObj ], function() {
    //code
});
```

Not sure what the problem is. Both objects are in the same function/scope.